# reshaping the a 2D array matlab

Tags: matlab, binary, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have a long binary string which i want to convert to n*8 dimension matrix in matlab.

I tried using reshape() but it works column wise and i am not able to obtain the output as it works column wise and not row wise.

i want to convert this:

011000010110111001100101011001010111001101101000

to this:

01100001

01101110

01100101

01100101

01110011

01101000

Is there any in-built method to work row-wise or is there any workaround to this silly issue?
PS: I tried using "transpose" but it gives me a 8*6 matrix which i do not desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
str = '011000010110111001100101011001010111001101101000';
reshape(str',8,[])'
```

**Output**

```
01100001
01101110
01100101
01100101
01110011
01101000
```

Comment: Thank you @Divakar, you made my final year project possible.

Comment: Wow, that's a final year project!? :)

Comment: That is the last step of the final year project which involves stegnography by matlab , cryptography by java and manipulating DCT co-effiecents.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Communications toolbox, you can also use [`vec2mat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html),  which works row-wise:

```
str = '011000010110111001100101011001010111001101101000';
result = vec2mat(str,8);
```